# Has anyone got parallax.js to work in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, parallax.js

I'm trying to create a simple version of this effect on Matthew Wagerfield's parallax.js site in my Vue3 site created with Vite and Typescript.

https://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

In the examples on GitHub https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax - I'm not sure where to put the examples given, specifically where to Run the Parallax: https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax#13-run-parallax

Is there anyone out there that has got this working inside this framework?

Things I have tried:

Including the example in the index.html page. (No errors - did nothing)

Including it in the script tag on the specific component I want to use it. (After 'fixing' a typscript error, it just didn't load the entire component - but the rest of the page loaded fine. No errors.)

If you have got this working in the Vite Vue3 TS framework - what did you do to get it working?